# How to create an empty dataframe and append to it without creating a new dataframe object?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm using the binance websocket to stream close data to a dataframe, and I need to be able to have an updated dataframe from those closes. But, with everything I try, pandas just creates a new dataframe object.

```py
if candle_closed:
     close = candle['c']

     df = pd.DataFrame()
     df = pd.concat((pd.DataFrame([close]), df), axis=0)

df
                0
0  20431.65000000
                0
0  20439.63000000
```

What I need:

```py
                0
1  20431.65000000
2  20439.63000000
```

Comment: Please read about how to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If you have two dataframes, then `pd.concat([df1, df2])` is all you need to do.

Comment: Do you have an existing dataframe you're trying to append to? Where is it defined? Why are you concatenating an empty dataframe in your code snippet? Presumably `candle['c']` *is already a dataframe* so why are you passing it to `pd.DataFrame()`?

Comment: @ddejohn candle['c'] is the streamed data from the websocket. I'm trying to get that data to append to the df dataframe I create. It's a string value.

Comment: Why append a dataframe to an empty dataframe? Why not just... directly use `candle['c']`?

Comment: @ddejohn If I do that, it outputs that only series and dataframe objects are valid for concatenation. Candle['c'] is a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, if you have an existing dataframe with "close" data, and you're getting a string from the websocket, then you need to use `pd.Series()` to first put the string into a `Series` object and then use `pd.concat()` with `ignore_index=True`:

```py
In [2]: df
Out[2]:
                0
0  20431.65000000

In [3]: c
Out[3]: '20439.63000000'

In [4]: df = pd.concat([df, pd.Series(c)], ignore_index=True)

In [5]:
Out[5]:
                0
0  20431.65000000
1  20439.63000000
```